# Using functions in data frame filter

Tags: r

I created a function like this:

```r
is_blank <- function(field) {
  if (length(field) == 0) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else if (nchar(trimws(field)) == 0) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

However, if I try and use this in a filter step with a dataframe as follows:

```r
field1 <- c('Not empty', NA, '', ' ')
frame <- data.frame(field1)
filtered_frame <- filter(frame, is_blank(field1))
```

then my function doesn't work. I notice that `field` in the function gets set to the entire content of the column rather than doing it element-wise.

If I instead just don't use a function, it works:

```r
filtered_frame <- filter(frame, length(field1) == 0 & nchar(trimws(field1)) > 0)
```

How can I use my function in my filter step like this? Bear in mind that I might need to string multiple together, e.g.

```r
filter(some_other_frame, is_blank(field1) | is_blank(field2))
```

Comment: The `is_blank` uses `if/else` which are not vectorized.  Instead use `ifelse`

Comment: Cheers @akrun, I didn't realise it would be that simple. Feel free to formulate this as an answer if you have time

Comment: `length` will refer to the number of values in the column - i.e., the number of rows. So filtering on `length(field1) == 0` is pointless - if there are 0 rows, there are no rows to remove. Your `nchar(trimws()) == 0` is sufficient, and your function could be `is_blank <- function(field) {nchar(trimws(field)) == 0}`. You could wrap it in `ifelse`, but it will just be extra overhead -- in general, `ifelse(condition, TRUE, FALSE)` is a long way of writing `condition` - `ifelse()` is useful when the values you want are more complicated than just a TRUE or FALSE.